# Packages for implementing following system and newsfeed like pinterest?

Tags: django, web, django-models, feed

I am currently developing an app in which I must be able to implement follow and followers system and also notifications and newsfeed.I came across various django packages,like for followers and following relations : django-relationships,django-follow,etc and for newsfeed : StreamFramework,django-notifier,django-notifications,etc.
So which are the best for implementing them together ? Which are the packages for getting both relations and newsfeed in my app ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to have a look at [getstream.io](https://getstream.io), an hosted API service that makes it really easy to build newsfeeds and notification feeds (with support for realtime updates). It comes with a [Django integration library](http://github.com/getstream/stream-django) that makes it really easy to add feeds to existing applications.

This is what it takes to keep a model in sync with user feeds for example:

```
from stream_django.activity import Activity


class Pin(models.Model, Activity):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
```

There is a Pinterest clone app built with django_stream here: https://github.com/GetStream/Stream-Example-Py

Disclaimer: I am one of the founders of getstream.io and contributor of StreamFramework.

Comment: I saw it.But I was unable to implement the followers-following thing in it.Can it be used for very large load ? I am new at it.Can you suggest any tutorials for it.Thanks!

Comment: @JaineshPatel yes, it is made to handle really very active applications (millions of users, billions of activities). Could you create a question here on stackoverflow about the issue you had or contact us at support@getstream.io?

Comment: Actually i was also confused with the paid services ? If I just use what is given in the clone what are the cons ??

Comment: Means which is better getstream.io or Stream-Framework ? I m totally confused ? Aint they same ?

Comment: the difference is that getstream.io is a hosted API and stream-framework an open source library.

Comment: I was having a look at your twitter clone on Github. @ https://gist.github.com/tbarbugli/97bf26f400ecf1443ef6 
but the link given at the end for the source code is not working.Can you please help with it ?

Comment: Can you show some examples like this with templates also.I saw the Pinterest clone but I didnt get a major part of it.Can I implement facebook style "Like" in this API ? Actually I cannot ask more questions on this site.So I am asking you here.Please help!Thanks!